# Flashing (R530 onboard) Dell PERC H730 mini to IT mode?

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc, lsi, firmware, jbod

Can I flash the firmware of the onboard PERC H730 mini (rebranded LSI) in a Dell R530 server?

Right now, I have it in pass-through mode, which works fine, but FreeBSD doesn't get any SMART data. With normal expansion card controllers, I would flash IT mode firmware, but I'm unsure if this is even possible with this particular controller, as it appears to be on the mainboard itself.

Answer (score 1):

PERC H730 [natively supports non-RAID/passthrough mode](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-HDD-SCSI-RAID/Dell-R730xd-with-PERC-H730-and-Non-RAID-HBA-mode/td-p/4504024), so you don't need to reflash it to have direct access to disks.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant by JBOD mode. It works fine indeed, but there is no SMART info available on FreeBSD. A ton of forum entries point to having to flash the firmware to enable this.

Comment: @crazor did you solve this? For my own sake could you please link to an example forum post?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. There doesn't seem to be a way with this controller. Even though FreeBSD/ZFS seem to run great with JBOD mode, the lack of SMART data is a big no-no. Stay away from this controller if you don't want to use it's native RAID functionality! Data WILL be lost! (Don't ask me how I know that)